# How to reference external file by adding TEXT(TODAY()) into path

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

Preparing worksheets which will compare data from two columns. One of columns will be linked with archived files from prior day. This is my cell formula:

`=VLOOKUP("Cash",'C:\...\"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy")&"\"&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")&"\"&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd")&"\[XXXX.xls]Check'!$L$10:$M$76,2,0)`

Is this formula proper? Still returning N/A. When I put date manualy it works fine. Seems that problem is with TEXT() formula. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. `VLOOKUP()` expects range reference as its second parameter. You are posting a reference to excel file named `'C:\...\"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy")&"\"&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")&"\"&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd")&"\[XXXX.xls]'` because your formulas and `&` operators will not be evaluated inside apostrophes `''`.

You need to wrap the string into `INDIRECT()` to evaluate it into reference:

```
=VLOOKUP("Cash",INDIRECT("'C:\...\"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy")&"\"&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm")&"\"&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd")&"\[XXXX.xls]Check'!$L$10:$M$76"),2,0)
```

However, don't expect this to open the whatever filename it calculates and fetch the data into your cell — it will return `#REF!` unless the file it is targeting is not open in Excel right now.

Comment: Your method worked but only if file is opened. Every time when I open my worksheets I receive `#REF` value in column, but value update every time when I open archived files.

Comment: Yes, I told this in my answer. You can't dynamically retrieve data from closed files using formulas alone. You will need to use VBA.

Comment: So is there any other solution? `VLOOKUP` works perfectly on current day files. But my worksheets will be comparing only prior day data. It would help me if I tell you that I don't need `VLOOKUP` function? I know exact range in other workbook with data, but it still need to remain in this form with `"&TEXT()&"`